# Can't run a windows form app on other PC, can't find a dll from a project of the same solution

Tags: c#, .net

(First things first, I'm kind of new on this type of programming)
I'm trying to make a windows form application where i request data from a PLC so it can be stored in a access database. This application is going to be running on a different computer.
On the solution i created and besides my project I'm using an existing project that works "like" the communication between the app and the PLC, it is called LibplctagWrapper (on my main project I create a reference to this last one)
(https://www.mesta-automation.com/how-to-communicate-to-an-allen-bradley-plc-with-c-and-libplctag-ethernet-ip-library/),
and it works on my PC, but every time y copy the Bin folder to the new computer, then run the app, it opens, but a warning popup messages appears. Saying: Unable to load DLL "plctag.dll": The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

The LibplctagWrapper is in another directory than my Solution and Main Project so I moved it to C: so the direction will be the same on the new computer. But it doesn't work.(copy the LibplctagWrapper in C: of the new pc as well)

Moved the entire solution/main project to C: as well... the same result.

Instead of just the bin folder i copied the entire project folder... im thinking the problem goes with the fact that the LibplctagWrapper is not in the same direction? but I don't know how to place it in the same direction... I search on visual studio but I never saw the option to move it.

Unable to load DLL "plctag.dll": The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

Comment: Read the actual words of the error message. *Unable to load DLL **"plctag.dll"***. That exact file needs to be on the computer, either in the same folder as your application or in a folder on the system PATH. Stop looking at `LibplctagWrapper` and start looking at the actual name of the DLL, and find and copy that DLL. The wrapper may wrap the functionality of the DLL, but the DLL itself has to be on the machine in order for that wrapper to work.

Comment: The DLL is actually in the same Bin folder, that's why I'm so confused, and just like i mentioned before, besides of this DLL being in the bin/debug folder, I removed the LibplctagWrapper from the solution, moved it to C:, then add it again. And in the new computer I copied the LibplctagWrapper to C: expecting that this way the dll would we found. (Didn't work).

Answer (score 0):

This error message is quite generic, missing dependencies can cause it as well as the mentioned module not being present at all. Check the Dependency Walker ( http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to discover required C++ runtimes or something alike. Remember to take x86/x64 into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

@JavierMata - I think you have probably resolved this issue, but for others encountering something similar you can use the recently released official wrappers which can be downloaded via nuget. Github link: https://github.com/libplctag/libplctag.NET

The libplctag.NativeImport package handles loading the appropriate C runtime so you don't have to.